# Капча jquery

Tags: jquery

Помогите найти простенькую капчу, картинку и поле. Погулил, действительно хороших вещей очень мало. Многие заброшены разрабами, многие использую php и перезагружают форму во время проверки.

Необходимо что-бы проверялась только по средствам jquery. (генератор картинки можно и на php).

Answer (score 1):

Может лучше взять [reСAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)?
На сегодняшний это лучший вариант из доступных.

Comment: большая больно

Comment: Зато надежная.